# Book about JCF and RCF matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book in linear algebra covering both JCF and RCF matrices.

Do you know a good one?

Comment: use Hoffman-Kunze

Answer (score 0):

how about an introduction to the theory of canonical matrices by turn bull and aitken.  within 200 page they get lots of things done. i like the books authored by a. c. aitken so i may be biased.